# Can to keep web app running even when the console closed?

Tags: web, gradle

I run "gradle tomcatRunWar" to start a web app running. When the console is closed, it will stop. How to keep the web app running even when console closed? I prefer not to use screen, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer not to use a multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`, you can use `nohup` as a simple one-liner.

The following command will run gradle in the background:

```
nohup gradle tomcatRunWar &
```

[Here is some more info on the nohup command.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html)